# Codeigniter image not uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to edit an upload an image to my database. However the image field do not get the value and comes out the filed is null.

**view:**

```
            <?php foreach($blog as $b){?>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('adminUpdatePost/'.$b->id); ?>" class="col s12">     
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"><?=$b->post?></textarea>
                            <label for="textarea1">Post</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                       <div class="btn">
                            <span>Post Image</span>
                            <input type="file" name="file">
                        </div>
                        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                            <input id="image" name="image" class="file-path validate" placeholder="<?=$b->image?>" type="text">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">                    
                </form>
                <?php } ?>
```

**controller:**

```
public function updatePost($id)
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => 'uploads/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png',
        'max_size' => 0,
        'filename' => url_title($this->input->post('file')),
        'encrypt_name' => false,
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('file');

    $post=array(         
        'post'=>$this->input->post('textarea1'), 
        'image'=>$this->upload->file_name,           //image 
    ); 

    ChromePhp::log("edit data : " . json_encode($post));

    $result = $this->AdminModel->updatePost($post, $id);    
}
```

When checking the content of $post array using ChromePhp the 'image' shows null value. But 'post' have values.

I cannot find where I have gone wrong. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the **"enctype="multipart/form-data""** type in form tage

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('adminUpdatePost/'.$b->id); ?>" class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this

```
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
                {
                      echo "<pre>";print_r($this->upload->display_errors());die();

                }
                else
                {
                     echo "nothing wrong";
                }
```

and show me the result. If that not help,  try to change

```
 <input type="file" name="file">
```

to

and change `$this->upload->do_upload('file')` to `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')`

Answer (score 1):

To upload image/file you need to add enctype attribute in you form tag

it should be like this

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('adminUpdatePost/'.$b->id); ?>" class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea"><?=$b->post?></textarea>
          <label for="textarea1">Post</label>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="file-field input-field">
     <div class="btn">
          <span>Post Image</span>
          <input type="file" name="file">
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input id="image" name="image" class="file-path validate" placeholder="<?=$b->image?>" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```